# How to have a div at 100%-Xpx height?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm having trouble with a simple div height and percentages. I have searched the net, but no luck. Here is the layout :

```
<div id="modal">
    <div id="modalHead">HEAD</div>
    <div id="modalBody">BODY</div>
</div>
```

Simple as that. The css (stripped down) :

```
#modal{position:fixed; top:0; left: 0; height:100%;}
#modalHead{height:40px}
#modalBody{height:100%}
```

Problem is that I get 100% height PLUS 40px. Resulting in a scrollbar of 40px extra. Because of that, i'm  I tried using negative margins, height:auto, but no luck. Is there a way of doing this?

Basically, what I want is something in the lines of height: 100%-40px.

Than you!

**edit:**
[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akKWu/1).

Comment: It (`modalBody`) should just stretch to take up the rest of the div if it's contents necessitate that much height. Is that not what you are looking for? Do you have a different background or something that makes it necessary for that div to take up the rest of the space no matter what?

Comment: @thatidiotguy modal should take 100% of the screen. Inside, modalHead take 40px height, and modalBody, the rest. (nice name)

Comment: @rahules Yes! The problem doesn't come from here. It comes from the 100% height PLUS the 40px from the div before.

Comment: I can provide a javascript solution (as well as other I am sure), but you have indeed stumped me on the css side. upvote!

Comment: @thatidiotguy If I could make a web page with javascript only, I think I would. Haha.

Comment: @Elggetto I don't seem to get a scrollbar when trying this in jsfiddle or as a separate html. Tried it in Chromium and FF16. That said, will trying overflow:hidden on the parent div solve your problem?

Comment: @rahules http://jsfiddle.net/akKWu/ There you go. Imagine #container is my page width and height (handheld). I need the scrollbar. I just don't want the extra 40px. I want something like 100% minus 40px.

Comment: Javascript adds functionality to a web page, you do not use to to create entire web pages. You could dynamically determine the height of your parent div, and then instead of relying on percentages, set the actual height of the bottom element to be `parentHeight-40`

Comment: @thatidiotguy I would if I could. Unfortunately, it's for a client and I cannot rely on javascript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#modal{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0}
#modalHead{height:40px}
#modalBody{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:40px;bottom:0}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it won't help me with my problem of 100%. modalBody takes the maximum height it can of his parents. If my screen have 500px height, the children will take 500px. I need a way to bypass this.

Comment: @Elggetto I'm puzzled by your answer here, Kolink's answer does exactly what you state. I'm not sure why the parent's come into it considering you are using `position:fixed` which will automatically snap to the viewport. Could you explain exactly what you need that is any different from what this answer provides? the calculation of `top:40px` to `bottom:0` works out as `100% - 40`

Comment: @pebbl Well, I tried this method and instead of hiding 40px of my scrollbar, it gives the `#modal` 100% of the viewport + 40px. The bottom 0 does nothing.

Comment: @Elggetto I've updated your jsfiddle (which differs slightly from the code in your question) with the basic answer that Kolink has given and it seems to work for me -- unless I really misunderstand. http://jsfiddle.net/akKWu/2/ You need to keep in mind that `#modalBody` can not have `height:100%` set as this will cause problems when mixed with `top:40px` and `bottom:0` .. you may also get issues using IE6 or below.

Comment: @pebbl I am officially retarded. I was so stuck on the 100% that I didn't think about taking it off... Thank You!! It works now. Sorry for wasting your time haha.

Comment: @Elggetto ah no worries and no waste of time at all. It's good to get things cleared up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all from your body tag and HTML

```
html, body{margin:0px; padding:0px border:0px}
```

Comment: What difference would that make? The container has `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just don't want the modalHead element to affect the modalBody's height, in which case you can just do:

```
#modalHead{height:40px; position: absolute;}
```

Once you have that, you can mess with the rest of it's dimension and placement using left and top if you need to.

edit:

Going off of your jsfiddle, I'd say the easiest solution would be to do as I suggested above and just add a margin-top: 40px or top: 40px (depending on the positioning) to the first element inside of the modalBody. In your jsfiddle example, that would be the p tag.

```
#modalBody p:first-child{margin-top: 40px;}
```

Comment: Problem is that the head now hides my body. If I add a padding or a margin of 40px, it gets added to the 100% height.

Comment: Right, so looking at your jsfiddle link, the container has a set height. If that's the case, just change the percentage of the body to compensate for the head height: modalHead(height)/modalBody(height). So in the case of your jsfiddle, the body's height should be 90% instead of 100% because 60px/600px = .1 or 10%. You also wouldn't use position absolute as I have suggested above. Make sense?

Comment: The container doesn't have a set height. It was just to illustrate the idea of a handheld device. It's gonna be variable. Your idea of first child isn't bad though! I'm gonna try it!

Comment: Almost! I'm losing part of the scrollbar under the header because of the absolute position.